# How to stop bundler to collide in a folder's package.json file with main app's package.json?

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm building a react native project. I kept my backend folder named sanity in app folder. My metro bundler colliding with app/package.json with app/sanity/package.json while opening in android but working with web. My terminal showing the below error.

jest-haste-map: Haste module naming collision: quick-bhai
The following files share their name; please adjust your hasteImpl:
* \package.json
* \sanity\package.json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had same name in both package.json file which was causing me this error. Check name if you're facing same kinda error.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).